# Непонятная ситуация с приложением android

Tags: java, android, activity, android-manifest

У меня есть приложение для андроид с определенным функционалом, одной из функций является логин при помощи retrofit, для того что-бы как-то продолжить работу с приложением после удачной авторизации, я сделал переход на другое активити например назовем ее seconscreen. То есть если мы вводим правильно пароль и логин то после нажатия на кнопку переходим на второе активити. В андроид студии есть такая функция как Build APK, для того что-бы создать файл-установщик программы. Я воспользовался данной функцией и создал данный файл. Потом я эту программу поставил на реальное устройство для проверки его работы, и вот что меня просто ОЧЕНЬ удивило, так это то что после установки у меня появилось вместо одного приложения, два а именно приложение с функцией логина, где мы можем залогинится и перейти на второй экран, и второе приложение которое состоит только из активити SeconScreen. Я не понял в чем причина такой странной инсталяции если честно. Может кто сталкивался с подобной ситуацией и знает в чем причина, буду очень благодарен за помощь и содействие в решении моего вопроса.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У вас в манифесте несколько `Activity` помечены как [`LAUNCHER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#CATEGORY_LAUNCHER):

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Только для основной `Activity` указывайте его:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```