# Unity admob, почему при установки апк на Андроиде создаётся два ярлыка?

Tags: unity3d, manifest, google-ads

Поставил google mobile ads, скомпилировал проект под андроид, установил, создалось 2 ярлыка. В чем подвох, как исправить? Думаю дело в манифесте

Comment: Если вы думаете, что дело в манифесте, то желательно, чтобы вы добавили его тест в вопрос, для этого воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править"

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Непонятная ситуация с приложением android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/856348/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-android)